# Grepping progressively through large file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have several large data files (~100MB-1GB of text) and a sorted list of tens of thousands of timestamps that index data points of interest. The timestamp file looks like:

```
12345
15467
67256
182387
199364
...
```

And the data file looks like:

```
Line of text
12345 0.234 0.123 2.321
More text
Some unimportant data
14509 0.987 0.543 3.600
More text
15467 0.678 0.345 4.431
```

The data in the second file is all in order of timestamp. I want to grep through the second file using the time stamps of the first, printing the timestamp and fourth data item in an output file. I've been using this:

```
grep -wf time.stamps data.file | awk '{print $1 "\t" $4 }'  >> output.file
```

This is taking on the order of a day to complete for each data file. The problem is that this command searches though the entire data file for every line in time.stamps, but I only need the search to pick up from the last data point. Is there any way to speed up this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this entirely in `awk` …

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}($1 in a){print $1,$4}' timestampfile datafile
```

Comment: +1: Took me a little time to understand how this works, but once I understood that the first part of the script was loading all the timestamps into the array `a` and the second part was checking for the presence in that array of the first field in the data file, I could see that this was a very elegant solution that only requires enough memory to store all the timestamps.

Comment: @Simon You are a quick learner my friend. It does exactly that. For further performance improvement you can delete the array element after it has matched. That would reduce the size for the next scan though it won't match if that element occurs again down the file.

Comment: Nice! Job that took 8 hours before now takes 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

JS웃's `awk` solution is probably the way to go. If `join` is available and the first field of the irrelevant "data" is not numeric, you could exploit the fact that the files are in the same order and avoid a sorting step. This example uses bash process substitution on linux

```
join  -o2.1,2.4 -1 1 -2 1 key.txt <(awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/' data.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

'grep' has a little used option `-f filename` which gets the patterns from filename and does the matching. It is likely to beat the `awk` solution and your timestamps would not have to be sorted.